# Angular ng-table header rowspan if no filter

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

How to add a rowspan to ng-table-dynamic header for non-filterable columns?

[image]
This example code can be found at http://codepen.io/ike3/pen/wzzgzG

All I want is to set `rowspan="2"` for Age and Money `th`'s. It seems I can create a custom template for both header and filter but cannot control the table structure itself.

Comment: Did you try http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-multi-template

Comment: It seems it allows to combine cells by `colspan`ing them but not for rows. I want to combine Money header with empty filter cell. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with jQuery but it looks like a hack:

custom filter template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/filters/rowspan">
    <filter-row-span></filter-row-span>
</script>
```

and a directive:

```
.directive('filterRowSpan', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var idx = $(element[0]).parents("th").index();
            var tbl = $(element[0]).parents(".table");
            for (var i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
                var rs = tbl.find("thead > tr:first-child th:nth-child(" + (1+i) + ")").attr("rowspan");
                if (rs) idx++;
            }
            tbl.find("thead > tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(" + (1+idx) + ")").remove();
            tbl.find("thead > tr:first-child th:nth-child(" + (1+idx) + ")").attr("rowspan", 2).addClass("no-filter");
        }
    };
})
```

Maybe there is a better way.